# What does 'the date is in my calendar' mean?

Tags: meaning, business-language, email

I received a single-sentence reply 'the date is in my calendar' when I asked a person to make an appointment with a specific date. I thought it means the date works for the person at the beginning. The opposite meaning has come to my mind shortly.

Which of the following interpretation (or neither of them) is correct?

> (1) (I have put) the date in my calendar. (so it works)
>
> (2) The date is (already) in my calendar. (so it doesn't work)

I failed to find the meaning on the web and I cannot ask the person directly.
Thank you!

Comment: It means choice 1- they’ve got your appointment recorded in their   calendar.

Comment: The best way is to ask the person directly.

Answer (score 1):

It means that (1) the date in question works for the speaker, *AND* (2) the speaker has added the meeting with you as a new appointment in his/her calendar. This is more emphatic/reassuring than "The date works for me"; it's a confirmation that the speaker has *formally agreed* to the date and, barring any other communication, *will see you at that time*.

Think of "date" in this context as a euphemism for "the event that will occur on that date." Unfortunately, it's quite an ambiguous word; the shade of meaning used in this example is most closely:

> 6. an appointment for a particular time: *They have a date with their accountant at ten o'clock.*  ([Source; see definition #6](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/date?s=t))

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like British parlance to my ear and indicates to me choice #1. I would expect a reply of "I have a conflict with that date/time," if the respondent could not meet me at my requested date/time. I'd also expect a counter offer for the requested meeting time/date.